# When Does Query Returns Null on Android?

Tags: android, sql, android-cursor

I don't seem to find any information on query, insert or any other SQL method returning null. But it does if error occurs.

I just wonder whether cursor being null means an error occurred or could it mean no rows were selected (for instance)? I don't know how I should treat it - as an error or something that may happen time to time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe you ever need to check `if(cursor == null) {}`.

**First**
If your query doesn't return any rows, you will receive an *empty* Cursor.  The Cursor will *not* be `null`.

There are many ways to check if a Cursor is empty:

- `if(cursor.getCount == 0) {}`
- `if(!cursor.moveToFirst()) {}`

In fact all of the Cursor#moveTo...() methods return either `true` or `false`, if you receive `false` then the row that you requested does not exist.

**Second**
If an error occurs then you need to catch the error in a try-catch block, otherwise the app will crash from an unhandled exception.

---

Also `insert()`, `update()`, and `delete()` return an integer, not a Cursor. These methods return the number of rows affected by your statement, if no rows are affected these methods return `0`.

Comment: So why do all example I see have code like `if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) { ... }` ?

Comment: It is possible (but illogical) to catch the error from creating a bad Cursor and _not_ create an alternate Cursor. This is the only time I know of that could create a null Cursor. However I believe if you are going to take the time to catch the exception, you should create a "default" Cursor (like an empty one).

Comment: It already happened to me, that the cursor returned from a rawQuery is always null, I don't know what's going on, the database is there, and it's not empty, the return value is ALWAYS null, it's not an empty cursor, it's just null. Don't know why. And I don't have any exception output, except when I move the cursor.

Comment: @Sam: ContentResolver.query and SQLiteDatabase.query throw exceptions. However, android.database.sqlite.SqliteWrapper.query returns null for exceptions, and most custom wrappers follow this convention

Comment: It happens on android, so check cursor ==null is a good practice

Comment: "A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry. May return null if the underlying content provider returns null, or if it crashes."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the Android source code, from https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java, where most queries end up:

```
public Cursor query(CursorFactory factory, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteQuery query = new SQLiteQuery(mDatabase, mSql, mCancellationSignal);
    final Cursor cursor;
    try {
        query.bindAllArgsAsStrings(selectionArgs);

        if (factory == null) {
            cursor = new SQLiteCursor(this, mEditTable, query);
        } else {
            cursor = factory.newCursor(mDatabase, this, mEditTable, query);
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        query.close();
        throw ex;
    }

    mQuery = query;
    return cursor;
}
```

You can easily see that in the only case the local variable for the `Cursor` is not assigned then a `RuntimeException` will be thrown instead. Meaning this function can not ever return null.

You can hypothetically get a `RuntimeException` from the factory if used. Looking at the constructors for `SQLiteQuery` and `SQLiteCursor` no exceptions appear to be thrown. You can get an `IllegalArgumentException` if your bindings are incorrect during `query.bindAllArgsAsStrings(selectionArgs);`

Note an `SQLiteException` can be thrown later from the `SQLiteQuery` when the non-null `Cursor` is read.

> That specific Android source code hasn't been updated since 2012. It is stable

Answer (score -3):

When a cursor results in no rows selected it returns (-1), if an error occurred the cursor can be null