# Does query ever return a null cursor

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I always see people say that it [cursor is never null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537493/when-does-query-returns-null-on-android/12537873#12537873) so you dont need to check for null or not but then there are other people that say that cursor can be null and you chould always check it.

so looking at the query method [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java) it does show that null gets returned so I dont know if I am just missing something or are the people saying that cursor is never null wrong?

do you or do you not need to check if `Cursor` is null when a query is made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `ContentResolver` queries, yes, the returned `Cursor` can be `null` as illustrated by the code you linked.

For `SQLiteDatabase` queries, no, checking for `null` `Cursor` is not necessary. Though it does not hurt much.

Answer (score 1):

[SQliteDatabase.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) returns a Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry. Cursor is never null but it can be empty.

For `ContentResolver queries` it can be null. Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080540/what-causes-androids-contentresolver-query-to-return-null).

Answer (score 0):

Be safe and make your code solid, check for null.
You can refer to [this code from Android](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%29). As we can see it is possible to get null.

Comment: I am sorry, what is wrong with my answer, please comment.